# How to make the placeholder text uppercase in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I want to change the placeholder in TextInput to uppercase without affecting the input. I intend to keep the input in lowercase. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to write `placeholder` value uppercase like below?

```
<TextInput
  placeholder={'TEST'}
  onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ text })}
  value={text}
  style={styles.input} 
/>
```

Comment: Yeah, it worked for me. Thanks! BTW, is there any way to achieve this by styling?

Comment: No, you can't control placeholder text style. You can just change your placeholder value and color. If my answer helps you, please accept as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change placeholder case then use javascript functions e.g.toUpperCase() as below:

```
<TextInput
  placeholder={String('test').toUpperCase()}
  onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ text })}
  value={text}
  style={styles.input} 
/>
```